# How can i get a correct comparison inside an if statement in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

im creating a batch file that checks if a log file is bigger than before, if is not it calls a monitor to begin, but i can't get the if block to work, is inside a if defined block but it doesnt goes to the else part and it always fail because it doesnt have a value.

I have tried to use delayed expansion but it either doesnt get a value, or it tries to evaluate with the name of the variable, but if i use only a line in the if defined block it works.

```
REM @echo off
REM SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
FOR /F %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c omcp_*.log') do set FILENAME=%%i
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%FILENAME%') DO set SIZE=%%~zA
IF DEFINED LASTFILENAME (
    IF %FILENAME% == %LASTFILENAME% (
        if DEFINED LASTSIZE (
            IF %SIZE%==%LASTSIZE% ( echo "subir monitor") else ( echo  "no subir monitor" )
        )
    )
) 
set LASTFILENAME=%FILENAME%
set LASTSIZE=%SIZE%

REM setx LASTFILENAME=%FILENAME%
REM setx LASTSIZE=%SIZE%
```

it should set the variables in the first run and show "no subir monitor" in the second run
Thanks

Comment: for each of your comparisons, use `IF "%FILENAME%" == "%LASTFILENAME%" (
` - quoting the values overcomes the `not defined` problem generating the syntax-error. It also caters for spaces in filenames, and the `if defined` guard can be removed. BTW - `set "FILENAME=%%i"&set "size=%%~zi"` should set `size` appropriately - the quotes ensure that the values assigned are appropriately delimited.

Comment: that fixed it :D thank you so much i have been trying to solve this thing since yesterday

Comment: The `if defined LASTNAME (` does not protect the inner `if %FILENAME% == %LASTFILENAME% (`, because even when the outer condition is not fulfilled, the whole block becomes parsed, leading to something like `if omcp_xyz.log ==  (`, for instance, which still constitutes a syntax error; quotation as suggested by Magoo makes the inner `if` condition safe...

Comment: @Magoo Make sure to post your solution as an answer here and OP please make sure to mark that solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

for each of your comparisons, use `IF "%FILENAME%" == "%LASTFILENAME%"` ( - quoting the values overcomes the not defined problem generating the syntax-error. It also caters for spaces in filenames, and the if defined guard can be removed. BTW - `set "FILENAME=%%i"&set "size=%%~zi"` should set size appropriately - the quotes ensure that the values assigned are appropriately delimited